# Can't see partitions and there is no windows 8 in grub

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, windows-8

I had windows 8.1 on my laptop. I have installed Ubuntu 14 04 and then when I restarted the computer there was no grub. and an automatic Ubuntu loading. Then I tried boot-repair. After that there was grub without windows 8 in it. What can I do?

P.S 1: My partitions were 3 NTFS for windows and 1 for Ubuntu. But now when I put a windows bootable cd, there is only one big partition(sum of those 3 without any free space)

P.S 2: Both OS are 64 bit.

P.S 3: If there is something else that I should mention please tell me.

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1940734

http://strangelyperfect.tv/6415/how-to-convert-a-dynamic-disk-to-basic-disk-in-windows-7/#sthash.Vg8xjUwp.dpbs

These two seems to be related to my problem.

Still any help would be highly welcomed.

Comment: Post this from live installer. sudo parted -l AND: sudo fdisk -lu Windows 8 if UEFI should not have dynamic partitions and Windows 8 pre-installed uses gpt partitioning (and fdisk will only give an error on that).

Comment: @oldfred: I didn't get what you said. Could you please tell it in another way?

Comment: Then post the link that Boot-Repair gives for its BootInfo report. Run a new report, but not new fixes, if you do not have link from original repair.

Answer (score 0):

You could have overridden it, but try ***sudo update-grub*** if you didn't override it, you should see it in ubuntu as a drive in the launcher.

Comment: this is not the problem. I haven't overridden it.It is about changing those 3 drives to dynamic. I've updated grub. Even windows bootable CD can't see them separately.